# openOptionsMenu doesn't work on Lollipop Tablet with minSdkVersion 16

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, tablet, android-optionsmenu

I have searched Stack Overflow but there is no link for exact same issue.

The app I am working on is a legacy app.
This app has to open options menu on tap of an image icon.
The app does not use action bar.
This feature was working fine, across devices, until I raised it's minSdkVersion to 16 form 8.
Since I raised minSdkVersion to 16 the options menu does not open on Lollipop Tablets. It works fine on Lollipop Smartphone though.

What is the issue here? Is there any workaround?

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: I haven't set it. Only set minSdkVersion as 16. also if I rollback it to 10 it works but it won't work if I set it to anything more than 10.

Comment: "I haven't set it" -- that makes no sense whatsoever. Set it to 8 and see if that helps.

Comment: Moving minSdkVersion to 10 or lower works for me. Can I keep minSdkVersion='16' and set targetSdkVersion='8' ? Will that break any other feature in app? I will try it and update you.

Comment: "Can I keep minSdkVersion='16' and set targetSdkVersion='8' ?" -- that is what I am suggesting that you try. "Will that break any other feature in app?" -- I don't think so, but you will need to test thoroughly.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes that worked. Sorry about late response. Didn't had my test device last night. This will require proper testing. If you write it as answer, I will accept it. Also let me know if there is an alternative way of doing it as well. Thanks for your prompt response!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Always* have a `targetSdkVersion` defined for your project. This tells Android "hey, I was thinking of this API level when I wrote this code". Android will use that for selective bits of forwards compatibility, changing runtime behavior on newer devices to be a little bit closer to what you were thinking of back then.

Tablets never really used the options menu; starting with Android 3.0, the former options menu was migrated to the action bar. In the absence of `targetSdkVersion`, apparently Android will treat the `minSdkVersion` as also being the `targetSdkVersion`. And, with a `minSdkVersion`/`targetSdkVersion` of 16, you are firmly into the action bar world.

Setting your `targetSdkVersion` to 8 should revert whatever changes were being applied by your `minSdkVersion` jumping to 16.

However, eventually something is going to force your hand to raise your `targetSdkVersion` to a higher value. Do not assume that you will be able to stick with a `targetSdkVersion` of 8 forever. Either:

- Migrate your users to the action bar, or
- Implement your own options menu lookalike, or
- Plan to replace the app in its entirety with a modern implementation, or
- Plan to abandon the app

Comment: Again, nice answer.